# Decomposition of the vector in terms of the basis

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra, vector

Let I have basis of two linearly independent vectors `{d[1,2], d[1,3]}`.
Let I need to decompose vector `5 d[1,2]` it terms of this basis.

I try to `Solve[5 d[1,2]==a d[1,2] +b d[1,3],{a,b}]`.

I expect solution

> {{a->5,b->0}}

but mathematica don't know that `d[1,2]` and `d[1,3]`are linearly independent. So I get solution, that I don't need:

> {{b -> (5 d[1, 2])/d[1, 3] - (a d[1, 2])/d[1, 3]}}

How to do I need?

(Further I will need to decompose vector like 
`12 + 2 d[1, 2] + 2 d[1, 3] + 2 d[1, 4] - 2 d[1, 5] + 2 d[2, 3] +  2 d[2, 4] - 2 d[2, 5] + 2 d[3, 4] - 2 d[3, 5] - 2 d[4, 5]` 
in terms of basis like 
`{1,`
`d[1, 2] + d[1, 3] + d[1, 4] + d[2, 3] + d[3, 4],`
`d[1, 5] + d[2, 5] + d[3, 5] + d[4, 5],`
`d[1, 2] d[3, 4] + d[1, 3] d[2, 4] + d[1, 4] d[3, 2],`
`d[1, 5] d[2, 3] + d[1, 5] d[2, 4] + d[1, 3] d[2, 5] + d[1, 4] d[2, 5] + d[1, 5] d[3, 4] + d[2, 5] d[3, 4] + d[1, 2] d[3, 5] + d[1, 4] d[3, 5] + d[2, 4] d[3, 5] + d[1, 2] d[4, 5] + d[1, 3] d[4, 5] + d[2, 3] d[4, 5]}`
and I expect something like `{12,2,-2,0,0}` or any error, if such decomposition is impossible.)

Comment: Maybe `Coefficient[5 d[1, 2], #] &/@ {d[1, 2], d[1, 3]}`

Comment: How can I get coefficient at 1? `Coefficient[1+2x+3y,x,0]`-> `1 + 3 y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vec = 12 + 2 d[1, 2] + 2 d[1, 3] + 2 d[1, 4] - 2 d[1, 5] + 2 d[2, 3] - 2 d[2, 5] + 2 d[3, 4] - 2 d[3, 5] - 2 d[4, 5];
basis = {1, d[1, 2] + d[1, 3] + d[1, 4] + d[2, 3] + d[3, 4], d[1, 5] + d[2, 5] + d[3, 5] + d[4, 5], d[1, 2] d[3, 4] + d[1, 3] d[2, 4] + d[1, 4] d[3, 2], d[1, 5] d[2, 3] + d[1, 5] d[2, 4] + d[1, 3] d[2, 5] + d[1, 4] d[2, 5] + d[1, 5] d[3, 4] + d[2, 5] d[3, 4] + d[1, 2] d[3, 5] + d[1, 4] d[3, 5] + d[2, 4] d[3, 5] + d[1, 2] d[4, 5] + d[1, 3] d[4, 5] + d[2, 3] d[4, 5]};

solve[b_, v_] := With[{symbs = Unique[ConstantArray["x", Length[b]]]},
 (Remove @@ symbs; #) &[symbs /. Solve[Union @@ Last[Reap[Collect[b.symbs - v,
                  Reverse[SortBy[Flatten[List @@@ b], Length]], Sow];]] == 0]]]

solve[basis, vec]
```

> ```
> {{12, 2, -2, 0, 0}}
> ```

Comment: be careful: for `List @@@ {1, a b, x + y}` I expect `{1,a b,{x,y}}` but it return `{1,{a,b},{x,y}}`

Comment: If `1` is absent in second argument of `Collect`, one works 10 times more faster.

Answer (score 5):

Use `SolveAlways`:

```
SolveAlways[5 d[1, 2] == a d[1, 2] + b d[1, 3], {d[1, 2], d[1, 3]}]
```

and

```
vector = 12 + 2 d[1, 2] + 2 d[1, 3] + 2 d[1, 4] - 2 d[1, 5] + 
   2 d[2, 3] - 2 d[2, 5] + 2 d[3, 4] - 2 d[3, 5] - 2 d[4, 5];
basis = {1, d[1, 2] + d[1, 3] + d[1, 4] + d[2, 3] + d[3, 4], 
  d[1, 5] + d[2, 5] + d[3, 5] + d[4, 5], 
  d[1, 2] d[3, 4] + d[1, 3] d[2, 4] + d[1, 4] d[3, 2], 
  d[1, 5] d[2, 3] + d[1, 5] d[2, 4] + d[1, 3] d[2, 5] + 
   d[1, 4] d[2, 5] + d[1, 5] d[3, 4] + d[2, 5] d[3, 4] + 
   d[1, 2] d[3, 5] + d[1, 4] d[3, 5] + d[2, 4] d[3, 5] + 
   d[1, 2] d[4, 5] + d[1, 3] d[4, 5] + d[2, 3] d[4, 5]}
len = Length[basis];
SolveAlways[vector == Array[c, len].basis, Variables[basis]]
```

`{{c[1] -> 12, c[2] -> 2, c[3] -> -2, c[4] -> 0, c[5] -> 0}}`

Comment: unfortunately when `basis//Length` =44, number of variables =28, number of terms in `Array[c, len].basis` =764 `SolveAlways` use so much memory that my computer freezes

Comment: @ФиляУсков This is a different problem. Your original question has been answered. Please, start a new question stating your problem and providing  your data.

Comment: No, your answer is not full, because your method is exponentially hard both in time and in memory.                             `len = 20;
MemoryConstrained[Timing[SolveAlways[5 e[3] == Array[c, len].Array[e, len],Array[e, len]]][[1]], 90000000]` -> `1.578125`                         `len = 21;MemoryConstrained[Timing[SolveAlways[5 e[3] == Array[c,len].Array[e, len], Array[e, len]]][[1]], 200000000]` -> `3.125000`               `len = 24; MemoryConstrained[Timing[SolveAlways[5 e[3] == Array[c, len].Array[e, len], Array[e, len]]][[1]], 1400000000]` -> 25.984375